# Can somebody please explain this Design for Welding guideline and its use case?

Tags: design, welding

[image]

This is the rule. Please help. Also identify a usecase.

Comment: What part of the rule is unclear?

Comment: In the figure on the right, what is the purpose of the part shown with darker cross-section?

Comment: are you asking about the one with the two dark sections?

Answer (score 0):

To make the square tube needs 4 welds ie 1 at each corner, but if two u sections are used then only 2 welds are needed. Fun Fact: Landrover used to make the first chassis for Landrovers like this and the welding machine could do 2 welds on the top, then the chassis was turned over and the other 2 welds completed - they hoped any heat bending evened out. It was apparently called the "christmas tree".

As welding is expensive (materials, labour, gas / electric) then minimising welding is usually the target by engineers and managers. In Fact welding courses usually show how to work out minimum weld lengths for many objects and some need some 'interesting" maths like cones and frustums.

Comment: Typically small square tubing is made with a single weld, Also most pipe is made with a single ERW weld.